Simultaneous usage of feature policy and permission policy in chrome still results in errors - how to implement
I'm working on a project that implements a Feature Policy header. This is due to be updated to Permission Policy. Since the coverage for this isn't optimal yet (no Firefox and Safari) I'd want to have them both enabled for now.
According to Chrome docs that's possible, and I've implemented them both side by side, but i'm still getting a lot of Error with Feature-Policy header warnings when opening the console.
Setting just the permission policy behaves as expected in Chrome, it works with no errors.
Setting both the headers at the same time will result in warnings in the console which I wouldn't expect there to be due to being overwritten according to the docs. They do seem to work fine together otherwise.
What is considered the best practise approach to configure feature/permission policy headers during this transition period?

Only use permission policy?
use both (ignore the warnings if those are not from me implementing something wrong)?
Any other option (checking the user agent string and impelmenting it 'smartly')?

Thanks in advance :)
